# How do I dynamically change padding depending on when view is focused vs not focused

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following relative layout
button_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/kiosk_tile_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kiosk_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following

```
val inflater =
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

buttonLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout, null, false)
...
buttonLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline)
```

Here's the outline.xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
            <padding
                android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Basically, I need have a border around the relative layout when the view is in focus and not have the border when it's out of focus. I need to add padding when adding border because if I don't, I don't see the border.

However, when the view is not in focus, I don't want to have the border and padding. Right now, it gets rid of the border when view goes out of focus but not padding.

So I added

```
<padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"/>
```

to the 2nd item. However, the when the view goes out of focus, it still has the 2dp padding. It looks like once the padding is added, it doesn't change.

How do I dynamically changing padding depending on when it's focused vs not focused?

Comment: Please upload a screenshoot, I think your view just not goes out of focus.

Comment: Did you try to call requestFocus() in the view?